# AUTOSAR NetworkHandleType values

Tags: autosar

Can one expect that all bus channels have unique NetworkHandleType identifier, that is that CAN channel and LIN channel can not have the same id? And can one expect that ids will be ordered and continuous, that is all CAN channel ids lie in the interval [CAN_STRT,CAN_STOP)? I hope my question does make sence, since I'm new to AUTOSAR. Sorry for my english, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you specify the exact parameter and module (ComM, CanIf etc) that you are asking about.

Comment: It's BswM module. Various bus managers send state indications of their channels, for example  BswM_CanSM_CurrentState(Network,CurrentState), BswM_FrSM_CurrentState(Network,CurrentState). The question is can BswM check that Network value is valid by simple comparisson NetworkMin <= Network && Network <= NetworkMax, or this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The function `BswM_CanSM_CurrentState` will take as a parameter of `network` the ComM Channel Id.

A LIN channel and CAN channel will have different ComM channel ID's.

There is no requirement that ComM channel ID's start from zero and be continuous. But generally, one would configure the values starting from zero.